# Вывод из БД

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
 name |  value
_________________
name1 | значение1
name2 | значение2
     ...
nameN | значениеN
```

Как оптимально вывести эти значения и присвоить их переменным...
Что б $name1 содержала значение1 и тд?

(Имена переменных и значений name совпадают)

Спасибо!

Comment: Оптимально было бы завести массив `name -> value`.

Comment: Тоже вариант. Как? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$r=mysql_query("select name,value from table");
while(list($name,$value)=mysql_fetch_array($r))${$name}=$value;
```

Все же, лучше не применять такое, дабы потом не отлавливать мистические ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому понадобиться... ответ:

//Получаем настройки сайта
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `site_settings`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$settings=array();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do {$settings[$row['name']]=$row['value'];}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
//print_r($settings);

(Продублируйте как нормальный ответ - ибо мне репутация не позволяет...)

Comment: О, увидел, что вы написали в принципе то же, что и я. Только цикл нужен с предусловием, на случай если таблица пустая.

+1.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с массивом такой:

```
$valueByName = array();

$result = mysql_query("select name, value from table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $valueByName[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```